# Why no "SELECT foo.* ... GROUP BY foo.id" in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select foo.*, count(bar.id)
from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id
group by foo.id
```

This worked great with SQLite and MySQL. Postgres however, complains about me not including all columns of foo in the `group by` clause. Why is this? Isn't it enough that foo.id is unique?

Comment: There's no group by clause in the statement... did you forget it?

Comment: Just because mysql accept it doesn't mean it's a good idea or a correct way

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just in case other people stumble over this question:

Starting with PostgreSQL 9.1 it's sufficient to list the columns of the primary key in the group by clause (so the example from the question would work now).

Comment: I could not cope with this strange behaviour of pg all the evening after migration from mysql :) Thanx

Comment: @kovpack: that's not a "strange behaviour" of Postgres. Postgres works as required in the SQL standard and as every other DBMS. It's MySQL that is strange here (not so say broken)

Answer (score 8):

Some databases are more relaxed about this, for good and bad. The query is unspecific, so the result is equally unspecific. If the database allows the query, it will return one record from each group and it won't care which one. Other databases are more specific, and require you to specify which value you want from the group. They won't let you write a query that has an unspecific result.

The only values that you can select without an aggregate is the ones in the `group by` clause:

```
select foo.id, count(bar.id)
from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id
group by foo.id
```

You can use aggregates to get other values:

```
select foo.id, min(foo.price), count(bar.id)
from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id
group by foo.id
```

If you want all the values from the foo table, you can either put them all in the `group by` clause (if that gives the correct result):

```
select foo.id, foo.price, foo.name, foo.address, count(bar.id)
from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id
group by foo.id, foo.price, foo.name, foo.address
```

Or, you can join the table with a subquery:

```
select foo.id, foo.price, foo.name, foo.address, sub.bar_count
from foo
inner join (
   select foo.id, bar_count = count(bar.id)
   from foo inner join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id
   group by foo.id
) sub on sub.id = foo.id
```

Comment: That last one will not work if there aren't any entries in bar for "a foo" you'll have to do:  SELECT foo.*, COALESCE(sub.bar_count) from foo left outer join (select ...) sub on sub.id = foo.id;

Comment: Also, you don't need to do a join in the subselect.

Comment: err.. my comment version missed a few characters. See my answer above for what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly would you have postgresql output? You're using an aggregate function and trying to output "something".

Ah. I see what you may want to do. Use a subselect.

```
select foo.*, (select count(*) from bar where bar.foo_id=foo.id) from foo;
```

Check with explain that the plan looks good though. A subselect is not always bad. I just checked with a database I'm using and my execution plan was good for that query.

Yes, in theory grouping by foo.id would be enough (i.e.: your query plus "group by foo.id"). But apparently (I tested it) postgresql will not do that. The other option is to "group by foo.id, foo.foo, foo.bar, foo.baz" and everything else that's in "foo.*".

Another way, that Guffa is on to, is this:

```
SELECT foo.*, COALESCE(sub.cnt, 0)
FROM foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT foo_id, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM bar
  GROUP BY foo_id) sub
ON sub.foo_id = foo.id;
```

This will be two queries though (one subquery, which is run just once), which can matter, but probably won't. If you can just do without "foo.*" you can use the second version that explicitly groups by all columns.

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` clause requires that every column that the query returns is either a column contained in the `GROUP BY` statement or an aggregate function (such as the `COUNT` in your example). Without seeing what your `GROUP BY` clause is or what the columns of `foo` are, it's hard to tell what exactly is going on, but I would guess the problem is that `foo.*` is trying to return one or several columns that are not in your `GROUP BY` clause.

This is really a general property of SQL and should not be specific to PostgreSQL. No idea why it worked for you with SQLite or MySQL -- perhaps all the columns in `foo.*` are actually in your `GROUP BY` clause but PostgreSQL can't figure that out -- so try listing out all of the columns of `foo` explicitly.